# UI-bootstrap datepicker ng-model $scope data not correct in controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, datepicker

I'm trying to use UI bootstraps datepicker to let a user select a date. The selected information I asume is stored in the ng-model **$scope.enddate** variable. After a date is picked, the correct information is displayed in the browser debugging section above.

**view**

```
<pre>
        ----------
        Debugging:
        {$ modelStartdate $}
        {$ !!partners.length $}

        Chosen stardate: The {$ startdate.getDate() $} of {$ startdate.getMonth() $}
        Chosen End-date: The {$ enddate.getDate() $} of {$ enddate.getMonth() $}
        Chosen Current year {$ enddate.getFullYear() $}
    </pre>
    <input            ng-click="openStartEndPicker($event, 'secondCal')"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      datepicker-popup="yyyy/MM/dd"
                      ng-model="enddate"
                      is-open="modelEnddate.secondCal"
                      name="secondCal"
                      max-date="'2015-06-22'"
                      datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                      date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                      ng-required="true"
                      close-text="Close"
                      datepicker-mode="month"/>

 <button ng-click="findNotLinkedPartners()" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
          <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"> Validate</i></span>
         </button>
```

On an ng-click event, I want to use this data to make a post request. 
But I always get the default information 2015 - 4 in the console??

**Controller:**

```
//Datepicker (selfenvoicing)
        $scope.startdate ='';
        $scope.enddate ='';

        //Set start end end date based on current day
        $scope.initDates = function() {
            var date = new Date();
            $scope.startdate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
            $scope.enddate  = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

            //Do initial partner validatioin with this year/month information (selve invoiking function)
        }();

        //In-calender functions/options
        $scope.today = function() {
            $scope.dt = new Date();
        }();

        $scope.toggleWeeks = function () {
            $scope.showWeeks = ! $scope.showWeeks;
        };
        $scope.clear = function () {
            $scope.dt = null;
        };
        $scope.toggleMin = function() {
            $scope.minDate = ( $scope.minDate ) ? null : new Date();
        }();
        $scope.dateOptions = {
            'year-format': "'yy'",
            'starting-day': 1
        };

        //trick to prevent not opening calender next time
        $scope.modelEnddate = {};

        $scope.openStartEndPicker = function($event, elementOpened) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.modelEnddate[elementOpened] = !$scope.modelEnddate[elementOpened];
        };
```

Function to be called:

```
$scope.findNotLinkedPartners = function() {

          console.log($scope.enddate.getFullYear() + " - " + $scope.enddate.getMonth());
  // POST request here
};
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a plnker? I would make sure that findNotLinkedPartners is in the same controller(scope) as the declaration of endDate as it's not clear from the snippets of code provided.

Answer (score 1):

you can call function on ng-change over INPUT element and send 'this' variable, then you will be able to access scope of the directive. using which you can set your controller models :-) **HAPPY CODING**

Answer (score 0):

Problem sovled. This answer helped me understanding the own private scope of the Datepicker. I could not access it on my own controller.

Thanks

[how to bind Bootstrap-datepicker element with angularjs ng-model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316937/bootstrap-datepicker-not-binding-with-angularjs-ng-model)