# forming an array from dynamic input fileds using angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, checkbox

I am working on a employee attendance system where i need to know their attendance status.I am generating a dynamic form which contains a text input field and a checkbox for each employee using angularjs ng-repeat inside a table to know whether the the employee was present or absent along with comments.I want to save the values of these dynamic text filed and checkbox using a single save button.Text fields may have null values or any other values and checkbox may be `all checked`,`all unchecked` and `few checked`  and `few unchecked`. If the check box is checked then i want to save `"checked":"yes"` otherwise as no.I have also a single date input field to save the record for this particular date.

I think the solution of my situation is forming a dynamic array from inputs and assign it to a variable but and don't know how to form array dynamically in angularjs and then pass the array to a php page.Can you help me on this issue?

My expected array format is :

```
[{"Did":"10","supervisor":"ms1001","date":"2017-06-01",
"info":
{"eid":"10","checked":"yes","cmnt":"on time"},
{"eid":"20","checked":"NO", "cmnt":"absent"},
{"eid":"30","checked":"yes","cmnt":""},
{"eid":"40","checked":"NO","cmnt":"OK"},
{"eid":"50","checked":"YES","cmnt":""},
{"eid":"60","checked":"YES","cmnt":""},
{"eid":"70","checked":"YES","cmnt":""},
{"eid":"80","checked":"NO","cmnt":"Late"},
{"eid":"90","checked":"YES","cmnt":""}
        }];
```

I will store the  input details in attendance table which schema is 
attendance`(did,eid,date,checked,comment,supervisor_id)`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [
    {"dept_id":"d10","dname":"sales","supervisor":"ms1001"},
    {"eid":"10","ename":"nam1"},

    {"eid":"20","ename":"nam2"},

    {"eid":"30","ename":"nam3"},

    {"eid":"40","ename":"nam4"},
    {"eid":"50","ename":"nam5"},

    {"eid":"60","ename":"nam6"},

    {"eid":"70","ename":"nam7"},
    {"eid":"80","ename":"nam8"},

    {"eid":"90","ename":"nam9"},

    {"eid":"120","ename":"nam10"}


    ];

        $scope.did= $scope.list[0].dept_id;
  
        $scope.dname= $scope.list[0].dname;
 $scope.sp_name= $scope.list[0].supervisor;
 


    $scope.selectedText = 'Select All';
     $scope.isAll = false;    
     $scope.selectAll = function() {
        
            if($scope.isAll === false) {
      angular.forEach($scope.list, function(data){
              data.checked = true;
      });
        $scope.isAll = true; 
        $scope.selectedText = 'Deselect All';
        } else {
        angular.forEach($scope.list, function(data){
              data.checked = false;
      });
        $scope.isAll = false; 
        $scope.selectedText = 'Select All';
        }
     };
      
        $scope.selectedFriends = function () {
        return $filter('filter')($scope.list, {checked: true });
   
      };
  
//date picker
  
  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };

 
  $scope.format = 'dd-MMMM-yyyy';


//end of date picker




    
});
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>  

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <style>
      .full button span {
        background-color: limegreen;
        border-radius: 32px;
        color: black;
      }
      .partially button span {
        background-color: orange;
        border-radius: 32px;
        color: black;
      }
    </style>

    </head>

    <div class="container">

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:yellow;">
             <p>Department ID::{{did}}</p>
            </div>

           <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:skyblue;">
            <p>Dept  Name:{{dname}}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:pink;">
             <p>Supervisor name name:{{sp_name}}</p>
             </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
              ng-model="list.dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2018-06-22'"
              ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}" 
              datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
              ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
            </p>
           </div>
      </div>


    <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
      <th>Employee ID</th>
     <th>name</th>
            <th><label>Attendence</label><br><span id="selectall" ng-click="selectAll()"><input 
        type="checkbox">{{selectedText}}</span></th>
    <th>comment</th>        

    </tr>  
     </thead>
        <tbody>
      
       <tr ng-repeat="data in list" ng-if="$index">
          <td> {{ data.eid }} </td>
          <td> {{ data.ename }} </td>

    <td> <input type="checkbox"  value="{{ data.eid}}"  ng-checked="data.checked" ng-model="data.checked"></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.cmnt" ></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

<pre>{{list}}</pre>
    </div>

    <button type="button" ng-click="saveAll()">Save all</button>
    </div>

    </html>
```

Comment: Are you saving this data to mysql?

Comment: but what is the question? to write all the logic for you starting from the frontend and ending to the store in the db?

Comment: i just want to form an array of all those inputs than catch it from a php page.so the question is how could i form the array in angular js  and how to access those variable in php  and for the rest  i know how to process it in php page!

Comment: yes i want to save this in mysql and i know how to do it.But  just facing problem in creating the array in angularjs and read it from a php page @VK321

Comment: @query - I asked you as the way you are doing is not correct. You may want to optimize logic as well.

Comment: any hints ? @VK321

Comment: I will write you soon... it will take a bit.

Comment: In the mean time if you can update your question with SQL schema you got.

Comment: i have updated my post,will be happy if you come with some help @VK321

Comment: I will make a script for you tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
    <td>Employee ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Attendance</td>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td>{{employee.eid}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.ename}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" ng-model="employee.att">
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<button ng-click="saveForm()">Save all</button>
<pre>{{employees}}</pre>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

//initial data to display on table.
$scope.employees = [
 {eid:"10",ename:"nam1", att: false},
 {eid:"20",ename:"nam2", att: false},
 {eid:"30",ename:"nam3", att: false},
];

//on save
$scope.saveForm = function (){

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/ana/testone',
    data: $.param({formData: angular.copy($scope.employees)}),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
});
```

**PHP**

```
$data = $_POST['formData'];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: i think we are almost close to the solution except one problem. If you look to my code snippet  you will see that there is a date picker out of the table.I need the the value of that date picker to be send within the same array.any idea how to achieve ?

Comment: not working as date picker is out side of the ng-repeat!

Comment: @query - <input type="text" class="form-control" 
     ng-model="employees.mydate" .......

Comment: @VK321-  still no effect!the date is not showing inside <pre></pre> tag. i have updated my code snippet kindly check it

Comment: @query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316937/how-to-bind-bootstrap-datepicker-element-with-angularjs-ng-model

Comment: i think my condition is little bit different however i have solved that in another way and thank you so much for your useful guidance for achieving my goal.Can you explain little bit your code  ? in php why we need to use json encode ?didn't we receive the data from angular in json format ?